# grunt compass generates file not accessible

Tags: grunt-contrib-compass

I have a grunt task to generate .css files from .sass

```
compass: { 
    dist: { 
        options: { 
            sassDir: 'app/styles',
            cssDir: 'app/styles',
            environment: 'development' // production for prod env
        }
    }
}
```

The css files generated are "rw-------". How should I config the task to set file permissions to what I want?

Comment: What are the permissions on the parent folder that holds the generated files?

Comment: I checked, parent dir and all outer directories are: 755 rwxr-xr-x

Answer (score 1):

The generated files inherit the permissions of the user who generates them you might be running it as the wrong user. That may be highly unlikely but check it . If you on Linux use `sudo` or `su`. If doesn't work i'm out of ideas as I stopped working with development in Linux as the xampp bugs me a lot. :)